# User input int to Array then use bubble sort to sort numbers

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

This is my first time posting to this blog.  I'm new to Java and I have an issue with using bubble sort when a user inputs a set of values.  Below is my code; however, I'm looking more for advice then an answer because I won't learn the language with the answer.

Thanks for your help and again sorry if my code is a little convoluted.  BTW, I just started to learn Java so I won't be able to follow very complex coding advice.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class bubbleSort{

    public static void main(String[] arg){

        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter total amount of numbers:" );

        int n = input.nextInt();

        int [] numbers = new int[n];

        System.out.println("Enter the numbers: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println(list(n));

        bubbleSort(n);

        System.out.println(list(n));    
    }


    public static void bubbleSort(int[] n){

        boolean flag;

        do{

            flag = false; 

            for(int i = 0; i < n.length - 1; i++){

                if (n[i] > n[i + 1]){

                    int temp = n[i];
                    n[i] = n[i + 1];
                    n[i + 1] = temp;

                    flag = true;
                }

            }

        } while (flag);
    }
 }
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: "_I have an issue_" Can you explain what the issue is? Is your program not running? Does it produce the wrong results? What's up?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils This will cause an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException during the `if (n[i] > n[i + 1])` check. ... Oh, he deleted his comment.

Comment: @Tom, I know; I'm silly.

Comment: I never said that :D.

Answer (score 0):

Your code got a bit confused when you started referring to an undefined identifier `list`.

I think you need:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));

bubbleSort(numbers);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

instead of:

```
System.out.println(list(n));

bubbleSort(n);

System.out.println(list(n));
```

`n` is the number of input numbers, not something you would want to sort. `numbers` contains the input data, and is a much more reasonable thing to sort.

Comment: Thank you so much...while I was debugging this code I tried your solution but I forgot to add the second () and to add s at the end of Arrays so I assumed that it was wrong.  Again thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are problems with your code.

> `System.out.println(list(n));//list(n)came out of nowhere`

And you code seem to only sort out one of the array elements.

> 

You can try this:

```
public class BubbleSort {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] myArray = new int[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
        myArray[i] = (int)(Math.random()* 100 + 1);
        System.out.print(myArray[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    bubbleSort(myArray);
}
public static void bubbleSort(int[] array){
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < array.length -1 - i; j++){
            if(array[j] > array[j+1]){
                int temp = array[j+1];
                array[j+1] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
    }
}
```